# Random data listing and grouping

Tags: php

I have a 9-person classroom. I want to randomly divide the students in this class into three-person classes. It keeps returning the same names in my query. How can I do this, can you help?
I listed all the students first. Then I want to randomly group them into three.

My source code:

```
<?php 

require 'db.php';

$students = $db->query('SELECT * FROM students')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<div class="container mt-2">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($students as $student): ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $student['id'] ?></th>
      <td><?php echo $student['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $student['no'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>


<?php

$randomstudents = $db->query('select * from students order by rand() limit 3')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
<h6>3 Person Classroom</h6>
<hr>
<ul>
<?php foreach($randomstudents as $rs): ?>
<li><?php echo $rs['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
<h6>3 Person Classroom</h6>
<hr>
<?php foreach($randomstudents as $rs): ?>
<li><?php echo $rs['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
<h6>3 Person Classroom</h6>
<hr>
<?php foreach($randomstudents as $rs): ?>
<li><?php echo $rs['name']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to `foreach` 3 times `$randomstudents` becouse it only has the 3 positions you need to "spread". Just use the exact position of the `array` `$randomstudents` using `$randomstudents[0]['name']` to echo the first one, removing the `foreach`, `$randomstudents[1]['name']` will be the second, and so on.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? For example, when I create a class of 4 people, how can I assign the remaining 1 person to the other class? How should I use the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use `array_chunk()`

```
<?php
$randomstudents = $db->query('select * from students order by rand()')
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$randomstudents = array_chunk($randomstudents, 3);

foreach ($randomstudents as $groupOfThree) :
?>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h6>3 Person Classroom</h6>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($groupOfThree as $rs): ?>
      <li><?php echo $rs['name']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```